# Translate encoding of android mail in R

Tags: r, email

## Problem

I am using the R package `mRpostman` to access my mail account using R. And everything works just fine when I fetch the mails that were sent from my computer to the dedicated mail adress via Thunderbird. But when I use my Android phone to do the same, then the text is weirdly encoded and not legible anymore. How do I fix that? I have tried using `base64enc::base64decode()` but I could not get that to work. I failed similarly by trying fo change the encoding via `Encoding()`.

## Reprex

I sent two mails. One from my Computer using Thunderbird and the text is simply "Sent from Thunderbird on Computer". The other mail was sent using my Android phone using the default mail app. This one contains only the text "Sent from Android".

```r
library(mRpostman) # for email communication

# Connect to mail server
imap_mail <- 'imaps://imap.gmail.com' # mail client
user_mail <- keyring::key_get('dataviz-mail')
password_mail <- keyring::key_get('dataviz-mail-password')
# Establish connection to imap server
con <- configure_imap(
  url = imap_mail,
  user = user_mail,
  password = password_mail
)

# Switch to Inbox
con$select_folder('Inbox') 

# Fetch Thunderbird mail
con$fetch_text(11)
#> $text11
#> [1] "Sent from thunderbird on computer\r\n\r\n"

# Fetch Android mail
con$fetch_text(12)
#> $text12
#> [1] "----_com.samsung.android.email_7640956728775490\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\nVGhpcyBtYWlsIGlzIHNlbnQgZnJvbSBBbmRyb2lk\r\n\r\n----_com.samsung.android.email_7640956728775490\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\nPGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0\r\nL2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLTgiPjwvaGVhZD48Ym9keSBkaXI9ImF1dG8iPlRoaXMgbWFpbCBp\r\ncyBzZW50IGZyb20gQW5kcm9pZDwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+\r\n\r\n----_com.samsung.android.email_7640956728775490--\r\n\r\n"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

## Update

The Solution from Allan Cameron works but removes the line breaks

```r
library(tidyverse)
text_that_should_contain_line_breaks <- "----_com.samsung.android.email_6729645824359240\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\naHR0cHM6Ly90d2l0dGVyLmNvbS9jX2dlYmhhcmQvc3RhdHVzLzE1MTA4NjcwMDkxMTM5MjM1ODg/\r\ncz0yMCZ0PWR0X3dvVkV2a3dPSjBfRGZUc2ttZUFIYW5kZHJhd24gZm9udCBoZWFkaW5nVm9uIG1l\r\naW5lbS9tZWluZXIgR2FsYXh5IGdlc2VuZGV0\r\n\r\n----_com.samsung.android.email_6729645824359240\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n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\r\nb2R5PjwvaHRtbD4=\r\n\r\n----_com.samsung.android.email_6729645824359240--\r\n\r\n"
decoded <- text_that_should_contain_line_breaks %>% 
  str_match('base64\\r\\n\\r\\n([[:alpha:][:digit:]/\\r\\n]*)----') %>% 
  .[, 2] %>% 
  base64enc::base64decode() %>% 
  rawToChar()
decoded
#> [1] "https://twitter.com/c_gebhard/status/1510867009113923588?s=20&t=dt_woVEvkwOJ0_DfTskmeAHanddrawn font headingVon meinem/meiner Galaxy gesendet"

# But should be
cat("https://twitter.com/c_gebhard/status/1510867009113923588?s=20&t=dt_woVEvkwOJ0_DfTskmeA\nHanddrawn font heading\nVon meinem/meiner Galaxy gesendet")
#> https://twitter.com/c_gebhard/status/1510867009113923588?s=20&t=dt_woVEvkwOJ0_DfTskmeA
#> Handdrawn font heading
#> Von meinem/meiner Galaxy gesendet
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The android string does contain the message in base 64 encoding, but it is embedded in other, non-base64 encoded text, so you have to extract it.

If we take the string from your question:

```r
text12 <-  "----_com.samsung.android.email_7640956728775490\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\nVGhpcyBtYWlsIGlzIHNlbnQgZnJvbSBBbmRyb2lk\r\n\r\n----_com.samsung.android.email_7640956728775490\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\nPGh0bWw+PGhlYWQ+PG1ldGEgaHR0cC1lcXVpdj0iQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0\r\nL2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLTgiPjwvaGVhZD48Ym9keSBkaXI9ImF1dG8iPlRoaXMgbWFpbCBp\r\ncyBzZW50IGZyb20gQW5kcm9pZDwvYm9keT48L2h0bWw+\r\n\r\n----_com.samsung.android.email_7640956728775490--\r\n\r\n"
```

Then we can carve out the base 64 string, decode it to bytes and convert to character like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(base64enc)

text12 %>%
  strsplit("base64\r\n\r\n") %>%
  pluck(1, 2) %>%
  strsplit("----") %>%
  pluck(1, 1) %>%
  gsub(pattern = "[\r\n]+", replacement = "", .) %>%
  base64decode() %>%
  rawToChar()
#> [1] "This mail is sent from Android"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

**Update**

It seems the message is stored twice: once in plain text, the second in html-formatted text. There are no actual line breaks in the plain text, and the html only has line breaks because of the `<br>` tags. The easiest way to get text with the line breaks preserved is to parse the html.

```
parsed_content <- text_that_should_contain_line_breaks %>%
  strsplit("base64\r\n\r\n") %>%
  pluck(1, 3) %>%
  strsplit("----") %>%
  pluck(1, 1) %>%
  base64decode() %>%
  rawToChar() %>%
  rvest::read_html() %>%
  rvest::html_text2()
```

So for example:

```
cat(parsed_content)
#> https://twitter.com/c_gebhard/status/1510867009113923588?s=20&t=dt_woVEvkwOJ0_DfTskmeA
#>
#>
#> Handdrawn font heading
#>
#>
#> Von meinem/meiner Galaxy gesendet
```

Comment: This works fine but I noticed that my line breaks are gone after decoding. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: I tried splitting at \r\n but that does not seem to correspond to the real line breaks and results in line breaks mid-sentence.

Comment: @AlbertRapp are you able to give a concrete example with line breaks that I can debug? You could edit your question with one and tag me here to let me know.

Comment: @AlbertRapp I've updated my answer to show how to better parse with line breaks.

Comment: Oh man, I was so close to the solution. I already tried to use `rvest` to translate the html text but I could not get `html_text2()` to work. Now I know that I need `read_html()` before that. Seriously, thank you!